# How do I appropriately use the backslash character in a string

Tags: r

How do I appropriately use the backslash character in a string ? I would like to have this `"The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380."` instead of `"The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380 ."` I included the backslash character `"\b"` before `.` but it did not work out.
Here is the code:

```
my_function <- function(fname, lname) {
print(paste("The product of", fname, "and", lname, "is", fname*lname,"."))}

my_function(4,2345)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Try `paste0` instead.

Comment: `print(paste("The product of ", fname, " and ", lname, " is ", fname*lname,".", sep=""))`

Comment: Or `paste0` but still keep spaces inside strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use `paste0` which is equivalent to `paste(..., sep="")`, but slightly more efficient.

```
my_function <- function(fname, lname) {
print(paste0("The product of ", fname, " and ", lname, " is ", fname*lname,"."))}

my_function(4,2345)
[1] "The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380."
```

Answer (score 3):

For readability of strings merged with variables, I recommend looking at the `sprintf()` function.

```
val1 <- 4
val2 <- 2345
sprintf("The product of %s and %s is %s.", val1, val2, val1 * val2)

[1] "The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380."
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat()` to print a string without encoding escape characters:

```r
my_message <- function(a, b) {
  paste("The product of", a, "and", b, "is", a * b, "\b.")
}

print(my_message(4, 2345))
#> [1] "The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380 \b."
cat(my_message(4, 2345), "\n")
#> The product of 4 and 2345 is 9380.
```

But likely in this case you wouldn’t want to use a backspace character.
Instead, you’d avoid inserting the space in the first place, like other
answers show.